# Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent() fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I'm trying to upload a file using the Html2 input type="file" and an angular2 http.post request. When the request reaches the web api, it fails in the

```
Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()
```

It **doesn't** fail when submitting the request using **Postman** (when I don't include Content-Type in the header because postman takes care of it).

See my code:
Html:

```
 <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.dwg,.jpeg,.jpg">
```

Service function:

```
uploadFile(event) {
    let fileUploadUrl = this.webApiFileUploadURL;
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this._http.post(`${this.webApiFileUploadURL}`, formData, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log('success'),
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
```

And the WebApi post request (fails at 
**if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())** ):

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
    {

        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) // Fails here 
        {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // This illustrates how to get the file names.
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [@Guy E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6721134), what was the exception? MS documentation doesn’t list the exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

After a thorough research - I've succeeded:
**No need to set the content-type header property when posting.**
I've removed it from my angular2 http.post request and the
Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent() in the web-api post method passed (same as in postman)

Comment: This stumped me for a bit, appreciated

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

If anyone else runs into this "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource."

You may need to add this in you webapiconfig

```
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
```

[Original Credit](https://c-sharpcode.com/thread/how-to-setup-a-webapi-controller-for-multipart-formdata/)

Answer (score 0):

After so much reading, my guess is that you need to save your uploaded files asychronously (i just refer to it as JQUERY_D_UPLOAD).
I've created this small ASP.NET C# async task below to get you started.
NOTE: should return a string eg return "This was created by onyangofred@gmail.com";
For more, find me in my turing.com/github/facebook/gmail accounts: (onyangofred)

```
    public async Task<string> SaveFile()
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];

                using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine("~/uploads", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, 4096, useAsync: true))
                {
                    await file.InputStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: NOTE: This is an async method. Therefore, it returns control to the calling method as the file (eg 2GB file size) is being saved in the background. For my MVC web application, the user even navigates to a different view/page/function. My break-point is hit 45 minutes later, signifying that the thread had not been aborted, but was being executed in the background. Its simply FANTASTIC